# Using replace method to replace only one char or string

Tags: java, string, replace

My problem is I want to only replace one specific char or part of the string and not the rest of the same char

my example

```
char one = '#';
char two = '#';
char three = '#';
char four = '#';
char five = '#';
char six = '#';
char seven = '#';
char eight = '#';
char nine = '#';

String chart = "\n"+ one + two + three + "\n" + four + five + six + "\n"+ seven 
     + eight + nine + "\n\n";

chart = chart.replace(five, '/');
System.out.print(chart);
```

It outputs: /// /// ///

Instead of: ### #/# ###

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Create a **StringBuilder** object from your String and use **charAt** method.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_charat.htm

And then call `toString`.

```
int replacePosition = 5;//Choose it.
String inputStr = getYourString();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputStr);
sb.chrAt(replacePosition);
String result = sb.toString();
```

If you have a String, and you want to replace only single its character which is repeated at least `n` times and replace its n-th occurrence (it is five in your example), then you need to find its position first and then apply the solution by using **StringBuilder.charAt()**.

To find index of your character, you can simply loop through charters, or use method **indexOf()**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

`n` times each time with new start position from previous call if the previous indexOf was positive.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java replace method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) takes 2 parameters - the character you want to replace, and the character you're replacing it with.
Since all your characters are the same, you don't want to use the `replace` method, but instead the `substring` method. [Here is the documentation for it.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
MatchResult findNthOccurance(int n, Pattern p, CharSequence src){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(src);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) m.find();
    return m;
}
```

Basically, it just calls find repeatedly on a Matcher obtained from the Pattern. Conveniently, a Matcher is also a MatchResult, so I can just return it straight up.

Answer (score 0):

In `position` variable store the no of occurrence that you want to replace.As in your case you were trying to replace 5th so it is stored as 5 now.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(chart);
    int count = 0;
    int position = 5;
    int index = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
        if (count == position - 1) {
            index = m.end();
        }
    }
    String regex = "([#\n]{" + index + "})(#)([#\\n]{1,})";
    chart = chart.replaceAll(regex, "$1/$3");
    System.out.println(chart);
```

What i am doing here is first i'll find at what character that n-1th occurrence ends and stored that in **index**.After that in **replaceAll** i have a regex which group the string in three part, one before the char to be replaced, next group contain only one char which is nth occurrence and last group contains remaining.  `$1/$3` means replace the whole string with **group1** followed by **/** followed by **group3**.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.replaceFirst("((#[^#]*){5})#", "$1/") ;
```

This replaces the (first) occurrence of the **6th** # by /, actually searching 5 groups of #..., followed by #.

Short though slow.